# FB.login() extended permissions

Tags: default, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following code to get permissions from the user for my facebook application.

```
function checkLoginStatus(response) {           
            if (response.authResponse) {
                //user is already logged in and connected                   
            } else {                
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        //user logged in                            
                    } else {
                        //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization                           
                    }
                }, {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me'});
            }
        }
```

I get a dialog box with followed with "Allow" and "Skip" buttons.![enter image description here][1]

Now, Even if I click on on "Don't Allow"(which appears on the x button) or click on the "Skip" button will add the application to my application settings, with "Post on my behalf"(publish stream) permission. Does it mean that "publish_stream" is the default permission for an app ?

thanks
    ashy